# webpack in production mode doesn't like let

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Disclaimer: I'm not primarily a web developer, and this is my first foray into the world of node, packages, npm, umd, webpack, and bundling.

I have a typescript project that builds and runs fine, currently configured to output webpack-compatible exports. I can use `webpack` with the `webpack.config.js` below to successfully build and use the app just fine:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // entry: './scripts/stats.js',
    entry: './scripts/app.js',
    output: {
        // library: 'stats',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'stats.bundle.js'
    },
    node: {
      fs: 'empty'
    }
}
```

However, if I try to build the bundle with `webpack -p` instead, I get Uglify errors about unexpected tokens for variables that are declared with `let` instead of `var`, like this:

```
ERROR in stats.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (results) [stats.bundle.js:47151,8]
```

Where the line in question is as follows:

```
47149 function SelectNodes(filter) {                                                                                                                                  
47150     var nodes = [];                                                                                                                                          
47151     let results = document.querySelectorAll(filter);                                                                                                         
47152     for (let i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {                                                                                                               
47153         nodes.push(results[i]);                                                                                                                              
47154     }                                                                                                                                                        
47155     return nodes;                                                                                                                                            
47156 }
```

Replacing `let` with `var` lets things proceed OK; but then it throws another error on the next usage of `let`.

I'm not using babel or any plugins. I'm trying to just get basic webpack working without any addons or complications before using transpilers, etc.

I *presume* that this is an issue with webpack in production mode not supporting the same ES standard as webpack in regular mode, but I'm not sure why there would be such a discrepancy. (This has been my experience with all of JS tooling, the quality of the build toolchain is all over the place, everything is a work in progress, nothing is standardized.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. So webpack isn't transforming your ES6 code down to ES5. It "works" in development because most modern browsers support ES6 syntax. So you go to check your work in the browser and your modern browser knows how to handle the ES6 syntax. Uglify doesn't understand ES6 (though the author is almost done with a new version which will support ES6). So you need to run your code through a loader that will break your ES6 code down to ES5. Most of the time babel-loader will work, but I don't know enough about typescript to give you an answer for that. I recommend https://survivejs.com/webpack/preface/ if you plan to work more with webpack custom configs in the future. It's the most comprehensive resource I've found for diving into the webpack world; probably because it is maintained by one of webpacks core contributors.

check https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm already transforming my typescript to JS (and can actually configure typescript to emit ES5 instead of ES6), but I guess my question is/was whether it was possible to get webpack to emit production-ready ES6 code (this is for an-house app, we have control over the browser). I guess the answer is no, unless the UglifyJS dependency can be configured/replaced with something else.

Comment: Uglify will only understand ES5, currently, I believe the maintainer is working on integrating ES6. So you either have to ditch Uglify and go with another uglifier/minifier or setup production to output ES5 so you can use UglifyJS

Comment: So you're saying it _is_ possible to have `webpack -p` use a different minifier?

Comment: Yup! I recommend this resource it may help you finding an alternative and is a great webpack resource maintained by one of the main contributors of webpack.

https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/minifying/#other-ways-to-minify-javascript

Comment: If I was helpful I'd appreciate a upvote, trying to get rep so i can contribute better! Thanks! Best of luck solving your problem!